# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException when casting integers at an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception, compare

The problem is at the `partition()`, which would read a `LinkedList` node and compare the data value of that node with an input int number. the program throws `NullPointerException` at the compare statement `node.data < x`. I cannot figure it out, could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

```
package Chapter2;
import java.util.*;
public class LinkedList2<E>{
    static class LinkedListNode<E>{
        E data;
        LinkedListNode<E> next;
    }

    private LinkedListNode<E> head;
    private LinkedListNode<E> tail;

    public LinkedList2(){
        this.head = new LinkedListNode<E>();
        this.tail = new LinkedListNode<E>();
        head.next = tail;
    }
    public void addLast(E e){
        LinkedListNode<E> node = new LinkedListNode<E>();
        tail.data = e;
        tail.next = node;
        tail = node;
    }

    public void print(){
        LinkedListNode<E> curr = head.next;
        while(curr.next != null){
            System.out.print(curr.data + " ");
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public LinkedListNode<Integer> partition(LinkedListNode<Integer> node, Integer x){
        LinkedListNode<Integer> beforeStart = null;
        LinkedListNode<Integer> beforeEnd = null;
        LinkedListNode<Integer> afterStart = null;
        LinkedListNode<Integer> afterEnd = null;

        while(node!= null){
            LinkedListNode<Integer> next = node.next;
            node.next = null;
            System.out.println(node.data);
            if(node.data < x){
                if(beforeStart == null){
                    beforeStart = node;
                    beforeEnd = beforeStart;
                }else{
                    beforeEnd.next = node;
                    beforeEnd = node;
                }
            }else{
                if(afterStart == null){
                    afterStart = node;
                    afterEnd = afterStart;
                }else{
                    afterEnd.next = node;
                    afterEnd = node;
                }
            }
            node = next;
        }
        if(beforeStart == null){
            return afterStart;
        }
        beforeEnd.next = afterStart;
        return beforeStart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        LinkedList2<Integer> listInt = new LinkedList2<Integer>();
        listInt.addLast(5);
        listInt.addLast(8);
        listInt.addLast(1);
        listInt.addLast(3);
        listInt.addLast(6);

        listInt.print();

        System.out.println(listInt.head.next.data);
        listInt.partition(listInt.head.next, 4);

        listInt.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the line `System.out.println(node.data);` output before it throws the error? And what is the full error message?

Comment: You should explain what partition should do, otherwise you get the answer "You get the exeption because node is null in that line"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, you are checking if the value of node.data is less than x. As node.data is an Integer type, it could quite possibly be null, meaning that this statement will throw a NullPointer. You could remedy this with a check in your while statement:

```
while(node != null && node.data != null){
   /* Your Code */
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, at the last iteration of the while loop, node would be null. But why could that happen? The iteration condition is node!=null.

Comment: Node would not be null. Node.data would be null due to the logical bomb in your addLast function which causes tail to be an empty node.

Comment: so while(node!= null&& node.data!=null) works good, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking that *node* is not *null*, but are not checking that the *node.data* isn't *null* either, so when comparing *null < x* the *NullPointerException* comes out.

The while condition is right since you want to iterate over every node, but the if condition should be something like this:

```
if(node.data != null && node.data < x){
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the loop sets `node` to `tail`. `tail.data` is `null` because it's not being set -- in `addLast()` you're setting `tail` to a `LinkedListNode` without setting its `data`. Thus `node != null` but `node.data` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're setting statements are what's causing this null pointer

You set the next node to be null here `LinkedListNode<Integer> next = node.next;`

```
node.next = null;
```

This will work for 1st pass, but the second time the node will be null because of the statements above (`node.next = null`)

Debug it and you will see.

Comment: `node.next` is null, but `next` is not, and `node` gets set to `next`, not `node.next`.